# How to set a different label for TalkBack for an application?

Tags: android, talkback

Assume that I have a cool awesome app, and because it's an awesome app it has to have a Web2.0 name, so lets call it something like **iFygs** (completely made up, sorry if someone actually has this app somewhere). I would like to keep the branding I have of the two words connected like the above. On the other hand, I would like to be relatively accessible where I can be and I think the above is clearly read as **I Figs**, not the one it reads now which sounds like **eh-fi-gs**

Is there a way to supply a contentDescription for an android's activity like you would for an ImageButton. Or is there a way to supply a translation specifically for screenreaders, like res/values-en-rUS-sr/ or something like that? Or is this just not possible to do because it's actually my home launcher that's doing it so I have no say how it works.

Comment: Nope, not yet. Kind of gave up...

Answer (score 1):

Give your activity a label in your manifest

```
<activity
   android:name="com.package.ifygs.activity"
   android:label="I Figs" />
```

You can also set a string resource in there. More info on that attribute here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: I have not run it but I believe this will not keep the branding as "IFigs" on the home screen launcher. If you believe this is false I can give it a try and accept your answer if it works.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but I do believe this will work.  Your application's label should be "iFygs" but the activity label doesn't have to be.